# Using ternary operator in echo?

Tags: php

How come I can use echo like this:

```
<?php echo false ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?> //no
```

But can't use it like this

```
<?php echo false ?? 'yes'; ?> //nothing output
```

Comment: First one is for checking the boolean evaluation of false. Second is checking for isset() of false. The [prosposal](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) says: `The coalesce, or ??, operator is added, which returns the result of its first operand if it exists and is not NULL, or else its second operand`.

Comment: `echo false;` should print nothing to the screen. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: [Check this for clarification](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ?? Operator in PHP is the Null Coalescing Operator:

```
expr1 ?? expr2;

expr1 is returned when expr1 exists and is NOT null; otherwise it returns expr2.
```

Since in this case expr1 is false but is set, this expression returns Boolean false.

Compare:

```
echo false ?? 'It is FALSE'; // won't be displayed
echo null ?? 'it is NULL'; // It will work
```

Echo does not output when passed Boolean false.

Answer (score 0):

as said, you're using the null coalescing operator here

It's checking if false is null

just want to add:
regular vs. shorthand ternary operation

```
echo false ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

is the same as

```
echo false ?: 'no';
```

So,

```
echo true ?: 'no';
```

will output 1, as ?: essentially skips the first expression

```
(condition) ? expression1 : expression2
```